# ESET detected incoming connection to Rundll32

Tags: firewalls

My ESET Smart Security 7 detected incoming connection from an external computer, since Rundll32 can be run by any programs on my computer and I don't know which program is doing this, so I am concerned.

Is there a way to check which program waiting and accepting this external connection from the Internet?

Answer (score 1):

rundll32.exe is used to execute code from a dll, so -assuming it's the legit rundll32- you would need to check which dll is being run, eg. with [ProcessExplorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/es-es/sysinternals/bb896653).